# Complex Analysis: Principle Part and Evaluating Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, laurent-series

I have two quick questions.

Identify the pole in the following function and find the res of said function at it's pole.

$(1)$\ $G(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}$

Here, $\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}=(a_0+a_1z+\frac{a_2z^2}{2!}+\frac{a_3z^3}{3!}+...)$

$\Rightarrow (1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-...)=(a_0+a_1z+\frac{a_2z^2}{2!}+\frac{a_3z^3}{3!}+...)(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-...)$

I'm a little confused how to determine the pole and the residue since there appears to be no negative powers of $(z-z_0)$, where $z_0$ is my undetermined singular point. I'm also stuck because $\sin(z)=0$ \, $\forall$ $z=\pi k$.

$(2)$ I want to evaluate this integral. $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2+\cos(\theta)}d\theta$. I know how to do this evaluation, but why can we say,

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2+\cos(\theta)}d\theta = \int_{|z|=1}f(z) \  dz$, where $f(z)=\frac{-2i}{z^2+4z+1}$. I don't understand why we can take the contour to be a circle of radius 1.

Comment: You're expanding cos(z)/sin(z) as a power series centered at zero - but there's a singularity at zero.

Comment: thanks that answers part of (1), so what should I be expanding it as?

Comment: As a Laurent series, though you won't know how low a power to start at until you determine the order of the pole.  To find the order, just use the Taylor series for $\sin$ at each of its zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

$$\frac{\cos{z}}{\sin{z}} = \frac{\displaystyle 1-\frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^4}{24}-\cdots}{\displaystyle z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}-\cdots} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{\displaystyle 1-\frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^4}{24}-\cdots}{\displaystyle 1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}-\cdots}$$

Then we may write that

$$\frac{\cos{z}}{\sin{z}} = \frac{1}{z} F(z)$$

where $F$ is analytic at $z=0$.

2) To get the rational function in $z$, you substituted $z=e^{i \theta}$, which is the parametric form of $|z|=1$, which is a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin.